# @PostConstruct method from service class, is not being implemented while running JUnit cases

Tags: spring, junit, postconstruct

In my MQ application, the flow of the program is **Route class -> Service class -> DAO class**. In the service class, I have used an objectMapper to register time module in an init method annotated with @PostConstruct as follows :

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
    .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
}
```

But while testing the service class with JUnit 5, I have mocked the DAO class and used @InjectMocks for the service class. But, the registration of time module which I had done in the method annotated with @PostConstruct is not loaded to the test class.

I tried two ways :

1. Using @PostConstruct in test class for registering time module.
2. Registering time module in @BeforeEach method.

Both don't seem to work. Is there a way to bring in the time registration in service class to the JUnit or a way to implement the @PostConstruct from service class to the test class?

Comment: Spring isn't managing the bean and thus does call the method. Apart from that doing this in an `@PostConstruct` seems wrong. This should be done in an `@Configuration` class that configures the `ObjectMapper`. When using the Spring `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` the `JavaTimeModule` will be registered automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You must write or Integration Test with `@SpringBootTest` annotation or will try use `@JsonTest`

Junit platform by default not implemented Spring beans lifecycle manager and for correctly testing SpringBoot i recommend use Integration Test.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class MyTest {
   @Test
   void foo() {}
}

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(lazyInit = true) //make test runing process faster
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```